# How to send a mutable list to another activty listview or recycleview in andoid studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I just want to make a home screen with four cards, and when you click on one, it takes you to a different screen or activity with its details! 
for example : 
as shown below, I want to click on Villa card and it navigate to the screen that hold a list of villas 
So the main idea is that I want to make one mutable list type of data class just like this: 
```
data class details (var id:String, var image:Int, var title:String)
```
and the mutable list goning to be this form:
```
var data=mutableListOf( //my code )
```
please tell me how to make something just like this or send me link of tutorial ! 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you want to pass a list to the detail view. If I understand you right you only need to pass a 'Villa' object to the detail screen. So create a class 'Villa' (you called it details but villa fits better):

```
data class Villa(val id: String, val image: Int, val title: String ...)
```

I would recommend to work with Fragments so you navigate from the HomeFragment to the DetailFragment. Then you can pass a villa object with SafeArgs. Just follow this tutorial for SafeArgs:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data

If you want to do the same with Activities (not recommended) your Villa class needs to implement Serializable interface:

```
data class Villa(val id: String, val image: Int, val title: String ...) : Serializable
```

Then you can navigate to the DetailActivity in your HomeActivity like that:

```
val intent = Intent(this, DetailActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("KEY", villaObject)
startActivity(intent)
```

In the DetailActivity you can get the villa object like that:

```
villaObject = intent.getSerializableExtra("KEY");
```